# jQuery find preceding non-ancestor element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can I match an element that is preceding of the current's parent.

`.parents('form')` and `.closest()` does not does the job because it's not ancestor element

`.prev()` doesn't works because it's not a sibling

**html example:**

```
<div class="somerandomname">
    <div class="contents">
        <h3 class="title">sadois</h3>
        <strong>strong</strong>
        <h3 class="nottitle">osdjia</h3>

        <div class="sod">
            <p class="paragraph">
                <a class="link1" href="#">link 1</a>
                <a class="link2" href="#">link 2</a>
                <a class="link3" href="#">link 1</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**associated js:**

```
$('p>a').hover(function(){
   $(this).closest('strong').css({'background': 'red'});
}, function(){
   $(this).closest('strong').css({'background': 'transparent'});
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3xBz/)

Comment: whats the `current` your talking about and what are you trying to select in the provided html?

Comment: according to his example he wants to select the strong when hovering over a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to assume you know some of the document structure. E.g:

```
$("strong", $(this).closest('div.container')).css({'background': 'red'});
```

I don't believe there's a way of assuming a traversal as it goes up the dom.

Answer (score 2):

is this what you're trying to do?

```
$(this).closest('.sod').siblings('strong')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D3xBz/1/

---

you could do it that way as well:

```
$(this).closest('.contents').find('>strong')
```

assuming that the .contents div exists in your actual code

Comment: That's it but with kind of different approach ... the HTML is completely different, so I cannot rely on having `div.sod`

Comment: yea, well it's hard to come up with a solution when the code in the question is completely different from the actual one

Answer (score 1):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to match the ancestor `<div>` element exposing the `sod` class, then use [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) with the [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector to match the preceding `<strong>` element:

```
$("p > a").hover(function() {
    $(this).closest(".sod")
           .prevAll("strong:last")
           .css("background", "red");
}, function() {
    $(this).closest(".sod")
           .prevAll("strong:last")
           .css("background", "transparent");
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D3xBz/5/).

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$(this).closest()`

This will work its way up the parent tree and return the closest value to what you want.

Comment: Read the question again: "`.closest()` does not does the job because it's not ancestor element"

Comment: `find` works the opposite way, it looks for descendant elements. That's not going to help in this case either. However, a combination of `closest` (to get `.somerandomname`) and then `find` (to get the required element) *could* work, depending on what the OP is actually trying to do.